# How to write a templated function that uses iterators and specific types

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I'm trying to write a function which can receive an iterator of std::pair (points along a curve) which can do linear interpolation for a given X and return Y.

A function signature similar to this would be great, but I can't figure out how to set up the template definition.

```cpp
template<class RandomAccessIterator, typename X, typename Y >
Y piecewiseLinearInterpolate(
    RandomAccessIterator begin, 
    RandomAccessIterator end,
    X x);
```

However, doing this results in template argument deduction/substitution failing.

This also fails to compile:

```cpp
template<class RandomAccessIterator, template <class X, class Y> class std::pair >
constexpr Y piecewiseLinearInterpolate(
    RandomAccessIterator begin,
    RandomAccessIterator end,
    X x);
```

I have gotten a function with the following function signature to work, but it requires me to specify the types contained in the pair.

```cpp
using AdcCount16 = uint16_t;
using Pressure = int;

template<class RandomAccessIterator>
Pressure piecewiseLinearInterpolate(
    RandomAccessIterator begin,
    RandomAccessIterator end,
    AdcCount16 x);
```

How can I write a generalized function which can receive a random access iterator of std::pair and a value of type X which returns a value of type Y?

**Edit:**

I am calling the function like this:

```cpp
using PressurePoint = std::pair<AdcCount16, Pressure>;

PressurePoint piecewise[] = {
    {0, 1},
    {2, 3},
    {5, 9}
};

Pressure p1 = piecewiseLinearInterpolate(
    std::cbegin(piecewise),
    std::cend(piecewise),
    3);

assert(p1 == 5);
```

Comment: Can you provide some code to show how you're using the templates that are not compiling for you?  The problem may be in how you're using the templates and not in the definitions.

Comment: using Itr = std::pair::iterator; template<class Itr, class X, class Y> Y pieceWiseLinearInterpolate (Itr begin, Itr end, X x); ---> will this not solve your problem?

Comment: I provided an example of how I am using the function. Rajkumar, that doesn't compile for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like this

```
template<class RandomAccessIterator>
auto piecewiseLinearInterpolate(
    RandomAccessIterator begin, 
    RandomAccessIterator end,
    decltype(begin->first)) -> 
               decltype(begin->second);
```

Comment: any reason to drop the name of the last parameter?

Comment: @generic_opto_guy it's not needed in the prototype, obviously needed in an actual implementation